# How to reduce multiple string values to predefined categories in a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to reduce values of a specific column in a dataframe based on a   predefined pattern matching categories.

Example:

```
  val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, "apple"),
  (2, "banana"),
  (3, "avocado"),
  (4, "potato"))).toDF("Id", "category")

Id  category
1   apple
2   banana
3   avocado
4   potato
```

Desired output:

```
  val df_reduced = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, "fruit"),
  (2, "fruit"),
  (3, "vegetable"),
  (4, "vegetable"))).toDF("Id", "category")

Id  category
1   fruit
2   fruit
3   vegetable
4   vegetable
```

This is the solution I came up with:

```
df.withColumn("category", when(col("category") === "apple", regexp_replace(col("category"), "apple", "fruit"))
              .otherwise(when(col("category") === "banana", regexp_replace(col("category"), "banana", "fruit"))
              .otherwise(when(col("category") === "avocado", regexp_replace(col("category"), "avocado", "vegetable"))
              .otherwise(when(col("category") === "potato", regexp_replace(col("category"), "potato", "vegetable"))
                         ))))
.show
```

I don't really like this nested when-otherwise approach, so I would like to know: is there a better, more idiomatic solution for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create *a lookup dataframe* as

```
val lookupDF = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("apple", "fruit"),
  ("banana", "fruit"),
  ("avocado", "vegetable"),
  ("potato", "vegetable"))).toDF("category", "category2")
//    +--------+---------+
//    |category|category2|
//    +--------+---------+
//    |apple   |fruit    |
//    |banana  |fruit    |
//    |avocado |vegetable|
//    |potato  |vegetable|
//    +--------+---------+
```

Since the *lookup dataframe* is definitely going to be small you can use `broadcast` function for `join`ing

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.join(broadcast(lookupDF), Seq("category"), "left")
    .select(col("Id"), col("category2").as("category"))
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---------+
|Id |category |
+---+---------+
|1  |fruit    |
|2  |fruit    |
|3  |vegetable|
|4  |vegetable|
+---+---------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

You've commented

> what about missing values? if I have a category in the original df that is not present in the lookup df? I get null, advice on how to tackle it? I would prefer to keep the original value if no match is found in the lookup table, but I am unable to do it with joins

To tackle such case you can use `when/otherwise` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.join(broadcast(lookupDF), Seq("category"), "left")
  .select(col("Id"), when(col("category2").isNotNull, col("category2")).otherwise(col("category")).as("category"))
  .show(false)
```

Comment: what about missing values? if I have a category in the original df that is not present in the lookup df?
I get null, advice on how to tackle it?
I would prefer to keep the original value if no match is found in the lookup table, but I am unable to do it with joins.

Comment: you can use when/otherwise for that case. do you need help on that? @Andreyn

Answer (score 1):

I think , you should take help of `map` and `udf` like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val map=Map("Apple"->"fruit","Mango"->"fruit","potato"->"vegetable","avocado"->"vegetable","Banana"->"fruit")

val replaceUDF=udf((name:String)=>map.getOrElse(name, name))
val outputdf=df.withColumn("new_category", replaceUDF(col("category"))
```

Sample Output:

```
+---+--------+------------+
| Id|category|new_category|
+---+--------+------------+
|  1|   Apple|       fruit|
|  2|  Banana|       fruit|
|  3|  potato|   vegetable|
|  4| avocado|   vegetable|
|  5|   Mango|       fruit|
+---+--------+------------+
```